# How does WebSocketClient pass authentication token in Apollo Client 3.0?

Tags: authentication, websocket, graphql, apollo-client, graphql-subscriptions

By Apollo GraphQL's official doc, Apollo Client 3.0 supports authentication of WebSocket for its subscriptions. Subscriptions should be authenticated by a secure token in many cases. It was the same to me. I followed the latest doc of authentication over WebSocket of Apollo Client([here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/subscriptions/)).

Doc:

[image]

My code:

```
import { WebSocketLink } from '@apollo/client/link/ws';

const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  uri: `${process.env.REACT_APP_WS_API}/graphql/`,
  options: {
    reconnect: true,
    connectionParams: {
      authToken: `${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`
    }
  }
})
```

Unfortunately, this authentication doesn't work at all. `graphql_jwt.exceptions.PermissionDenied` error occurred in my `Django` backend and no `authToken` value was read by the backend. I've attached a screenshot of the exception below.

[image]

Is there any valid solution to pass a secure token to `WebSocketLink`?

Answer (score 0):

If the backend is expecting the token via headers, `WebSocketLink` may not work, because it sends the connectionParams as the payload property of a message over the `WebSocket` ([see code](https://github.com/apollographql/subscriptions-transport-ws/blob/e25d67ff9bcbdf9dc39cb8ddbbd0e75853252f1d/src/client.ts#L558-L559)). To make it work, backend would have to wait for the GQL_CONNECTION_INIT message to get the token.